# How to enable/disable next input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to enable disable very next input field with check uncheck of a closest checkbox.
I tried the following script.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check:checkbox', function(){
if (this.checked) {
        $(this).next().prop('disabled', false);
}else{
        $(this).next(".inputs").prop("disabled", true);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"one">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
<input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class"two">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
<input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class"three">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
<input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).next()` is the `<label>`, not `<input>`

Comment: @Barmar So how could we select that closest  input  field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your HTML stands, `.next()` points to the *label* element.

You should first target the closest *div* then find the respective element from that *div* element:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.inputs')
```

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check:checkbox', function(){
  var currentEl = $(this).closest('div').find('.inputs');
  if (this.checked) {
    currentEl.prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
    currentEl.prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"one">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class"two">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class"three">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).next()` is the `<label>`, and next after that is `<br>`.

Use `.nextAll()` to get all the following siblings that match a selector, and `.first()` to get the first one of these.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check:checkbox', function() {
  let nextinput = $(this).nextAll(".inputs").first();
  nextinput.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class "one">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class "two">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class "three">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. `next()` element is not input, it's label so why your code is fail. You can increase the `next()`(`next().next()...`) until you find proper element.

There are several way to find desire input to enable/disable. If your DOM is not changeable and there are only 1 sibling input use `siblings('input')`.

Example:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check:checkbox', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(".inputs").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class "one">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class "two">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
<div class "three">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <label> Enable/Disable</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `<label>`, wrapping the checkbox. This will improve the user experience. Then change the jQuery selector to `$(this).closest("div").find(".inputs")` in order to address the right input element.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check:checkbox', function(){
 $(this).closest("div").find(".inputs").prop('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"one">
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check">
Enable/Disable</label><br>
<input type="text" class="inputs" disabled value="a">
</div>
<div class"two">
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check">
Enable/Disable</label><br>
<input type="text" class="inputs" disabled value="b">
</div>
<div class"three">
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check">
Enable/Disable</label><br>
<input type="text" class="inputs" disabled value="c">
</div>
```